# Regex pattern to produce appropriate escape character behavior

Tags: regex, yaml, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting

I'm making a Sublime Text 3 language definition for syntax highlighting. The language is a simple 'expression language' (nothing to do with Java) that is used to display information from a media library on a display panel. The purpose of the syntax highlighting is to clarify exactly what will be displayed on the panel.

Accordingly, I would like to explicate exactly what a sequence of escape characters will look like when interpreted and shown on the display panel. The escape character is a forward-slash, and if you would like to display a literal forward-slash, you have to escape it with another. Therefore, a series of forward-slashes will result in every-other forward-slash being displayed on the panel. Additionally, if there is a special character after a forward-slash, it will be escaped - but if a special character is placed after TWO (or four, or six...) forward slashes, it will not be escaped, because the escape characters will cancel each other out.

The highlighting I would like to achieve (with example special character 's') is as follows:

[image: Desired Highlighting]

I have to achieve this simply by feeding Sublime Text regular expressions, in YAML format, so the solution has to be one made purely of regex.

Is this possible? If so, how can I achieve it?

Comment: You don't want an odd number of slashes. You want pairs of slashes to become a literal slash, and after that, single slashes are escape chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so for what it's worth, I figured it out. This:

```
%YAML 1.2
---

file_extensions:
  - example

  scope: source.example

  contexts:
    main:
    # special color setup #

    - match: s
      scope: green


    # desired behaviour #

      - match: '(/)(.)?'
        captures:
          1: grey
          2: white
```

Gives you this:

[image: Appropriate representation of escape character behaviour]

Answer (score 0):

Finding odd numbers of slashes is not particularly useful. This is a parsing exercise of removing slashes. If the slash is followed by another slash, it's a literal slash, otherwise it's whatever follows.

But wait a minute, there's no difference there - no matter what the following char is, it's  a literal, so...

Match all "slash-anychar" pairs using the regex `/(.)` and replace with the captured character.

In java:

```
str = str.replaceAll("/(.)", "$1");
```

In python:

```
str = re.sub('/(.)', '$1', str)
```

In perl:

```
$str =~ s/\/(.)/$1/
```

etc

Comment: If only it were that simple! I'm in YAML so I need a purely regex solution. I should have added a YAML tag. I'm going to do that now.

Comment: @dan what does YAML have to do with your question? You can’t “do” anything *in* YAML - it’s pure data. Please explain more in your question what you’re trying to do.

Comment: Perhaps saying I'm 'in YAML' was confusing, but my point is that I am not not programming anything - I am feeding instructions to a program, and those instructions are in YAML format. The instructions contain regular expressions, and if I feed in the correct regular expressions, the program will exhibit the behavior that I require of it. The program is Sublime Text 3, and the behavior is syntax highlighting. So I just need a pure regex solution to picking out the pattern described in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information on the structure of the syntax you currently have, it's hard to say for sure, but I think what you're looking for here is just a simple single `match` construct that matches the literal character `/` followed by any character that is allowed to be an escape character, which in your example is the character `s` and the character `/`.

You may be getting hung up on thinking that the regular expression that you're trying to create needs to find the biggest possible match containing any combination of escape sequences. However, the `match` rules that you provide are used as many times as needed to consume the input, so they only need to match single syntax constructs at a time.

A simple example of this in action is the following minimal syntax. The first two `match` constructs are just for example purposes in the image below; they implement a line comment and flagging an 's' as special when it's not escaped so that it's clearer when that is the case.

The third rule is what matches a valid escape sequence, which is a `/` followed by either another `/` (literal `/`) or an `s` (literal `s`).

The last rule, which is optional, matches a `/` character followed by anything that's not a valid escape character (including not being followed by anything) and marks it as `invalid` as a hint to the user that they've done something silly.

Here I've added a space character as a potentially valid escape for the purposes of invalid escape detection so that a trailing space following a bare `/` doesn't get the `invalid` scope as well. Without that, the syntax assumes you were trying to quote the space character.

```yaml
%YAML 1.2
---
scope: source.example
contexts:
  main:
    # A simple single-line comment scope capture for nice output
    - match: '(#).*\n?'
      captures:
        0: comment.line.number-sign.example
        1: punctuation.definition.comment.example
    # Just so we can apply a color to the letter s to know when it's "special"
    - match: 's'
      scope: entity.name.special
    # The set of things that can be valid escapes
    - match: '/[s/]'
      scope: constant.character.escape.example
    # If only s and / are valid escapes, make other escapes invalid, including
    # using a bare / with nothing following it.
    - match: '/[^s/ ]?'
      scope: invalid.illegal.escape.example
```

In a simple test, the results of this syntax would be:

[image: Syntax example]

Comment: Thanks. I might go with this solution at a pinch... I can see now how I didn't explain myself fully, though (I'm effectively new to Stack Overflow, new to Sublime Text, New to YAML and relatively new to Regex, so I'm generally a bit flummoxed). I have revised my question to make explicit exactly what I am trying to achieve - I think that should make it clear - would you mind taking a look?

Comment: For clarity, do you expect that when you enter some text in the file, the syntax highlight is also going to modify the text to remove some of the `/` characters, etc?

Comment: No. No modification of text, just the highlighting as shown, to indicate what WILL BE removed by the expression interpreter of the display.

Comment: You see how the grey slashes are easy to ignore and so make it much easier to visualize what the display will look like after the interpreter has done its work?